# how to scrape off such information

Tags: r, web-scraping

I just started learning parsing, the starting point was [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/beginners-guide-on-web-scraping-in-r-using-rvest-with-hands-on-knowledge/) article

I want to scrape off this one value from [this site](https://www.dailyfx.com/sentiment)
[image]

I use the program  Selector Gadget  to get tags which is described in the [article](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/beginners-guide-on-web-scraping-in-r-using-rvest-with-hands-on-knowledge/)
Here is the process of getting the tag
[image]

But i get nothing.
Here is my code.

```
library('rvest')
    link <- "https://www.dailyfx.com/sentiment"
    wp <- read_html(link)
    bal <- html_nodes(wp, ".dfx-technicalSentimentCard--opened .dfx-technicalSentimentCard__netLongContainer .font-weight-bold") 
    bal <- html_text(bal)
```

res

```
 bal
  character(0)
```

Can someone show me how to do it correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately that article doesn't mention that most modern webpages use a lot of javascript to add content to their pages after the initial page loads. Tools like `rvest` cannot run the javascript necessary to modify the pages. When seeing what's "really" on the page be sure to check the page "Source", not the "Elements". If you need to get values added by javascript then you'll need to use something like [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSelenium) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply .. If you have the time and desire to show me how to do this using RSelenium, then I would be very happy

Comment: There are plenty of examples on how to use RSelenium out there, see http://joshuamccrain.com/tutorials/web_scraping_R_selenium.html for example. First try something then if you get stuck you can ask a more specific question. It doesn't make a lot of sense to have a Stack Overflow question for every possible website that people might want to scrape since this is very site specific.

Comment: ok, thank you for your help, I'll go study